# What does it mean for a function to be bounded on its domain?

Tags: functions, metric-spaces

Suppose $S$ is an abstract metric space.

Suppose $f(x):\Bbb{S} \to \Bbb{R}$. Then how what would the question be asking, if it asks "Show that $f$ is not bounded on $\Bbb{S}$"?

Is it asking me to show that $f$ isn't bounded on the codomain $\Bbb{R}$, for all terms in the domain? So I just need to show that there doesn't exist a Least upper bound/greatest lower bound, for $f(x)$.

Or does it mean for me to show that $f$ isn't bounded on the domain? Would I need to show that there is no Least upper bound or Greatest lower bound for the elements in the domain? How would I show something like greatest or least, in abstract metric spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Good question. The terminology "bounded on the domain" is a little confusing at first, for the reasons you mention. It means the first thing you mention. But of course the codomain may be unbounded, although $f$ is bounded.

The reason for the terminology is that sometimes $f$ is defined on an even larger set...for instance we might have $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and we might say "$f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$." That would mean that if we just take $x$ values in $[0,1]$, there is some value in the codomain that $f$ stays below.

Answer (score 0):

Function $f:X\rightarrow (Y,d)$ (where $X$ is an arbitrary set) on set $X$ is called [bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function) if for some $a\in X$ there exists a real number $M$ such that its distance function $d$ ("distance") is less than $M$, i.e.
$$d(f(x),a)<M$$
for all $x\in X$.